# Captcha not every time load in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

in react if I loading the page some time captcha is rendering/loading sometimes its not loading. so how to give some condition such a way that if page load every time we should have to see the captcha. But in my case all time page is refreshing. how to give some dependency condition

```
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

export default function DropDown() {
  function onChange(value) {
    console.log("Captcha value:", value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); },1000);
  }, [ReCAPTCHA])
 
  return (
    <>
      <ReCAPTCHA sitekey="Your client site key"
                 onChange={onChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this an invisible captcha? That is, it does not show unless Google thinks it necesary

Comment: no this is not invisible captcha